# How to get current location in android app?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, android-location

First I apologize for the duplication, I know this question was asked and I tried to follow up the existing answers, but it wont work. So if you can please see my code and say what is wrong or missing, that would help me a lot.

Here's the activity, it uses only the Log (no GUI).

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager lManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    0, 0, this);
        else
            Log.i("Test", "network provider unavailable");

        Location lastKnownLocation =
                lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
            Log.i("Test", lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() + ", "
                    + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            lManager.removeUpdates(this);
        } else
            Log.i("Test", "null");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("Test", "location changed: " + location.getLatitude() + ", "
                + location.getLongitude());
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

when I try to run the app everything seems to work but latitude and longitude wont show on the log. I am using a real device with network location on for testing.

Comment: Your code looks ok. (Minor change: Rather than request an update then possibly cancel the update if there is a last known location, I would ask if there is a last know location and only then request updates if necessary.) It is possible that you cannot get a location because the signal is weak, the network is outdated, or perhaps you haven't waited long enough... Have you also tried GPS?

Comment: I didn't try GPS because it is said to be slower than network, and I don't need the accuracy it provides. Besides I need my device indoors connected to the pc for testing and log viewing. I was kind of hoping it could be done via network, and I have been waiting pretty long. How long can it take?

Comment: In ideal conditions getting a location should only take a few moments, if it takes longer than a few minutes then you are unlikely to ever get a signal. (I have to walk outside to get a fix...) Consider testing with mock locations.

Comment: The process of getting latitude and longitude takes 3 to 5 seconds, and you remove the Listener before getting those items,I think you have to delay the process of removing the listener to get the latitude and longitude

Comment: @Husam A. Al-ahmadi thanks, I did put the getLastKnownLocation call before the requestLocationUpdates call as Sam offered eventually, which fixed this issue as well. But thanks for showing me this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I couldn't get the location is the cellular company does not give that information (NETWORK_PROVIDER uses cellular antenna triangulation to determine location. Cellular company can provide or deny you this information).